# minimum set cover with no overlapping element between solution sets

Tags: set, minimum, cover

I am trying to solve a sub problem of set cover.
For example, the U={ (1,2,3), (4,3), (5,3), (1,2), (4) }
I want to find the minimum number of sets that cover all the elements in U, however with a constraint that the solution set should not have overlapping element between them.
In this case, a subset {(5,3), (1,2), (4)} is a solution,
but the subset {(1,2,3), (4,3), (5,3)} is not a solution.

Has anyone already studied this before? What is it called in the literature? Any algorithm suggested?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Exact Cover problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover